# Correct css syntax for inline base64 images

Tags: css

Whats wrong with this? is raising a linter error:

```
.scrollbar-light > .scroll-element .scroll-element_size {
    background: #dbdbdb;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi
    8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2
    VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaW
    VudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2
    Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2RiZGJkYiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMC
    UiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlOGU4ZTgiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD
    0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdm
    c+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #dbdbdb 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#dbdbdb), color-stop(100%,#e8e8e8));
}
```

I've tried adding quotes, same result.

Comment: Looks alright to me, but please do not break the lines. It should be in a single line. What's the error in the linter?

Answer (score 1):

The url is in multiple lines, change it to a single line

Answer (score 0):

You are **not supposed** to break the `dataURI` into different lines. The following CSS should work:

```
.scrollbar-light > .scroll-element .scroll-element_size {
  background: #dbdbdb;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #dbdbdb 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#dbdbdb), color-stop(100%,#e8e8e8));
}
```

The [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/) shows only one warning:

> **Require all gradient definitions**
>
> Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Webkit (Safari 5+, Chrome), Opera 11.1+.
>
> ```
> .scrollbar-light > .scroll-element .scroll-element_size {
> ```